# Quarkus - How to dynamically update properties at runtime

Tags: dynamic, configuration, runtime, quarkus

We have an application that is multi tenant, the user has the option to select what company he will connect to. The company is simply a different database, need to point hibernate orm to this new database instead of the one that is set in application.properties file after logging in.

Please, help, thanks.

After googling a lot I can not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: This piece of documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multitenancy should cover what you need. You may need to pay attention to the _Programmatically Resolving Tenants Connections_ paragraph.